# Spring Security Session handling how does it handle session id

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

actually I'm just starting to play around spring mvc in webapp and I have tumble across spring security which handles the authentication and session. My question is how does it handles session and can I create my own session id reference for spring security to use. I did use spring security but somewhat I feel blinded by it's process. Another thing is that can I add my own session service that I can control more if its implementable can you give me an insight in where can I start.. Furthermore I'm sorry for my English and if it is a duplicate question, though I think that topics concerning with spring security doesn't satisfy what i had in mind... Thanks for the feedback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security handles sessions nicely on its own. If you make a request, it'll append the session id in the response. You can read it and store it if you want to, so you can send it back as a cookie. We use this method with our Android application, because it does not handle it automatically as web browsers do. 
If you're making a web application, the browser will store and send back the session id, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: hi Marcee thanks for the tip I'll try to read Spring Security further though doubt still in mind...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that spring security implementation is not tied to HTTP session directly, take a look at this package `org.springframework.security.core.session`, There is `SessionCreationEvent`, `SessionDestroyedEvent` and `SessionInformation`. `SessionInformation` assumes that you have a String ID for the session but nothing else.

Now of you take a look at `SessionRegistryImpl` the java doc says you have to add `org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher` to your web.xml for the registry to be notified of the session events. So if you want to provide your own implementation of session management just replace `HttpSessionEventPublisher`  with your own implementation.

Comment: my I ask does replace HttpSessionEventPublisher by extending it or in other means?